# Normal mapping bug

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, game-engine, lwjgl

Im working on a 3D OpenGL engine with the LWJGL. I managed to do the model importing part with Assimp, now working on the normal mapping.
Luckily Assimp can calculate tangent space for me, but it isn't working correctly.
Here is a picture how is it working on the sponza model:

[image: Original]

This is the T visualized from TBN matrix:

[image: Tangents]

The code looks like this in the vertex shader:

```
mat3 normalMatrix = transpose(inverse(mat3(transformationMatrix)));
vec3 T = normalize(normalMatrix * tangent);
vec3 N = normalize(normalMatrix * normal);
T = normalize(T - dot(T, N) * N);
vec3 B = normalize(normalMatrix * bitangent);

if (dot(cross(N, T), B) < 0.0){
        T = T * -1.0;
}
TBN = transpose(mat3(T, B, N));
```

Its checking if the model has symetric UVs, and fixes it.
I think this causes the problem, because the B from TBN looks even worse.

[image: Bitangents from Assimp]

After weeks i tried to calculate tangents and bitangent by myself, but my bitangents are looking worse than Assimps:

[image: own Bitangents]

```
private void generateTangentBitangent(){
    for(int i = 0; i < indices.size(); i+=3){
        Vector3f v0 = new Vector3f (vertices.get(indices.get(i)).getPos());
        Vector3f v1 = new Vector3f (vertices.get(indices.get(i+1)).getPos());
        Vector3f v2 = new Vector3f (vertices.get(indices.get(i+2)).getPos());

        Vector2f uv0 = new Vector2f (vertices.get(indices.get(i)).getTextureCoord());
        Vector2f uv1 = new Vector2f (vertices.get(indices.get(i+1)).getTextureCoord());
        Vector2f uv2 = new Vector2f (vertices.get(indices.get(i+2)).getTextureCoord());

        Vector3f e1 = new Vector3f (v1.sub(v0));
        Vector3f e2 = new Vector3f (v2.sub(v0));

        Vector2f deltaUV1 = new Vector2f (uv1.sub(uv0));
        Vector2f deltaUV2 = new Vector2f (uv2.sub(uv0));

        float r = (float) (1.0f / (deltaUV1.x() * deltaUV2.y() - deltaUV1.y() * deltaUV2.x()));

        Vector3f tangent = new Vector3f ((e1.mul(deltaUV2.y()).sub(e2.mul(deltaUV1.y()))).mul(r));
        //System.out.println(tangent);
        Vector3f bitangent = new Vector3f ((e2.mul(deltaUV1.x()).sub(e1.mul(deltaUV2.x()))).mul(r));

        if(vertices.get(indices.get(i)).getTangent() == null)
            vertices.get(indices.get(i)).setTangent(new Vector3f(0,0,0));
        if(vertices.get(indices.get(i)).getBitangent() == null)
            vertices.get(indices.get(i)).setBitangent(new Vector3f(0,0,0));
        if(vertices.get(indices.get(i+1)).getTangent() == null)
            vertices.get(indices.get(i+1)).setTangent(new Vector3f(0,0,0));
        if(vertices.get(indices.get(i+1)).getBitangent() == null)
            vertices.get(indices.get(i+1)).setBitangent(new Vector3f(0,0,0));
        if(vertices.get(indices.get(i+2)).getTangent() == null)
            vertices.get(indices.get(i+2)).setTangent(new Vector3f(0,0,0));
        if(vertices.get(indices.get(i+2)).getBitangent() == null)
            vertices.get(indices.get(i+2)).setBitangent(new Vector3f(0,0,0));

        vertices.get(indices.get(i)).getTangent().add(tangent);
        vertices.get(indices.get(i)).getBitangent().add(bitangent);
        vertices.get(indices.get(i+1)).getTangent().add(tangent);
        vertices.get(indices.get(i+1)).getBitangent().add(bitangent);
        vertices.get(indices.get(i+2)).getTangent().add(tangent);
        vertices.get(indices.get(i+2)).getBitangent().add(bitangent);
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < vertices.size() ; i++) {
        vertices.get(i).getTangent().normalize();
        vertices.get(i).getBitangent().normalize();
    } 
}
```

Can someone help me please what causes the problem ?

Comment: `tangent` and `bitangent` must be transformed with `transformationMatrix`, not with `normalMatrix`. Then, all of your checks should not be necessary. What exactly is the problem? The pictures you showed do not look wrong per se. We would need to see the parameterization and the coordinate system to see if those make sense.

Comment: If i transform it with mat3(transformationMatrix) i get the same result, normalMatrixis just the inverse and transpose of transformationMatrix. When i try to use symmetric models, UVs are oriented in the wrong way, thats why i need to check it. The problem is, that the tangents and bitangents are calculated wrong. On the second pic, you can see that every flag has 2 "gradients" in it. Also there are more errors, like this: https://imgur.com/a/AOYDQ

Comment: it is better to render TBN as vectors (3 lines per vertex) instead of pixel color. But for that you need to add debug rendering code doing it (you can not do that in shader unless geometry shader pass is used ....)  Hope you are transforming vectors with matrices with origin set to `(0,0,0)` otherwise you will offset them (like points) invalidating their value

Comment: Question #1) Just to make sure: Have you specified the `aiProcess_CalcTangentSpace` flag when importing the asset with Assimp?

Comment: Question #2) What is the purpose of `T = normalize(T - dot(T, N) * N);` in your shader?

Comment: Question #3) What is the purpose of `if (dot(cross(N, T), B) < 0.0){
        T = T * -1.0;
}` in your shader?

Comment: Q #1) Yes, i did!
Q #2) It re-orthogonalizes the TBN vectors. (Gram-Schmidt process)
Q #3) It check's if the model has symertric UVs, and fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

In which space are the tangents/bitangents/normals which you present on your images? Judging from your code sample, they are probably expected to be in tangent space.

However, getting the tangent space vectors can be achieved easier. You don't have to Transform `tangent`, `normal`, and `bitangent` with `normalMatrix`, but instead just use the axes in object space:

```
vec3 normalOS    = normalize(normal);
vec3 tangentOS   = normalize(tangent);
vec3 bitangentOS = normalize(bitangent) // or calculate via cross(normalOS, tangentOS);
mat3 TStoOS      = mat3(tangentOS, bitangentOS, normalOS); // transform from tangent space into object space
mat3 OStoTS      = transpose(matrixTStoOS); // The transpose of an orthogonal matrix is it's inverse matrix
```

If you need the matrix, which transforms from tangent space into world space, you would calculate it like follows:

```
vec3 normalWS    = normalize(normalMatrix * normal);
vec3 tangentWS   = normalize(normalMatrix * tangent);
vec3 bitangentWS = normalize(cross(normalWS, tangentWS))
mat3 TStoWS      = mat3(tangentWS, bitangentWS, normalWS); // transform from tangent space into world space
mat3 WStoTS      = transpose(matrixTStoWS); // transform from world space into tangent space
```

Comment: I could generate the images showing the tangents/bitangents/normals like on your posted images using my implementation and the tangents and bitangents as generated by Assimp for the sponza 3D model. Please let me know, if that would help you.

Comment: Wow, you just fixed my lighting issue, thanks! (cause my lights were off too)
But the upper floor flags, still look weird: https://imgur.com/QBXQrui
Btw if i use my calculations, the lighting is still off.
Thanks, but you dont need to generate those images, i know roughly how this should look like.